# Flow screen needs to be default to top of page

Tags: visual-flows, scrolling, uiscrollerwrapper

I am using flow screens for form. By default when the screen opens, it defaults to the middle of the page. Is there a way, I can make it default to top of the page.

Thanks

Comment: Known issue, being addressed in the the Summer '19 release. The next screen will scroll back up to the first field in the form (on desktop anyway, still working on mobile).

Comment: I still have that issue in my flow. Is it because I created the flow before Summer 19 release? What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Is your org on the Summer '19 release? Only sandbox releases have this at this point.